# MFC 6.0 added Ribbon does not display

Tags: c++, user-interface, mfc

I would like to put lipstick on a pig. A MFC 6.0 MDI application that would like to have a ribbon.

I followed the most excellent example at [Walkthrough:Updating a pig](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb983935%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

The Ribbon did not show up, and nothing is barking... ie it can create it and load it. So I went back and downloaded the Scribble code that is mentioned at the link, and followed the instructions and that worked just fine... of course

I was able to convert to Office 2007 themes.

So I am looking for advice on how to debug this issue.

Comment: *"The Ribbon did not show up [...] ie it can create it and load it."* That sounds like an outrageously inappropriate guesstimate. Have you considered using a debugger to verify that the ribbon is properly created?

Answer (score 0):

There are a thousand chances to mess it up. This is how you should proceed:

1) Create a new project with Ribbon interface.

2) Compare all ressources and classes with your incompletely converted project (i.e. check if you have used `CWinAppEx` instead of `CWinApp` or `CMDIFrameWndEx` instead of `CMDIFrameWnd` everywhere)